# Read file with parameters as parameter in powershell script

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have tried to do a powershell script the reads a file with parameters:

File with parameters (`params.ini`):

```
[domain]
domain="google.com"
[port]
port="80"
```

Powershell script that reads the file:

```
Get-Content "params.ini" | ForEach-Object -Begin {$settings=@{}} -Process {$store = [regex]::split($_,'='); if(($store[0].CompareTo("") -ne 0) -and ($store[0].StartsWith("[") -ne $True) -and ($store[0].StartsWith("#") -ne $True)) {$settings.Add($store[0], $store[1])}}

$Param1 = $settings.Get_Item("domain")
$Param2 = $settings.Get_Item("port")

# Displaying the parameters
Write-Host "Domain: $Param1";
Write-Host "Port: $Param2";
```

But I want the file to be read by parameter. For example:

```
> scriptExample.ps1 -file C:\params.ini
```

What changes should I apply?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you need to handle Arguments.

`$file` contains the `-file` argument value that you will use within your script.

---

Non mandatory Argument :

```
Param(
  [string]$file
)
```

---

Mandatory Argument :

```
Param(
  [parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$file
)
```

---

Full code (using mandatory argument) :

```
Param(
  [parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$file
)

Get-Content "$file" | ForEach-Object -Begin {$settings=@{}} -Process {$store = [regex]::split($_,'='); if(($store[0].CompareTo("") -ne 0) -and ($store[0].StartsWith("[") -ne $True) -and ($store[0].StartsWith("#") -ne $True)) {$settings.Add($store[0], $store[1])}}

$Param1 = $settings.Get_Item("domain")
$Param2 = $settings.Get_Item("port")

# Displaying the parameters
Write-Host "Domain: $Param1";
Write-Host "Port: $Param2";
```

---

```
.\scriptExample.ps1 -file params.ini
Domain: "google.com"
Port: "80"
```